# Cannot find module 'docs.mdx' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, mdx, typescript-typings, storybook, type-declaration

When I'm going to import a file with the extension `.docs.mdx` into a `typescript file (.tsx)` it gives this error:

[image: Cannot find module 'docs.mdx' or its corresponding type declarations.]

I tried to create in the `root` of my project and in the `src` folder, a folder called `@types`, and inside it I created an `index.d.ts` with the following code:

> declare module '*.docs.mdx';

Did not work. So I changed the name from `index.d.ts` to `mdx.d.ts` and then to `docs.mdx.d.ts` and it still didn't work.

Finally, I tried to add this `Type Declaration` in the `typeRoots` that is in `tsconfig.json`, like this:

[image: tsconfig.json]

It didn't work either, the error remains.

Does anyone have any solutions, please?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the file i was editing was in the `exclude` list of tsconfig, which is odd